# How to get specific value from a string?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in having string value like

```
"BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR "
```

I need to get the  the code written between * and - 
Example `0112305V7`. Can someone help me for this issue

Comment: In above example you have two `*`. Do you always want from second `*` and first `-` after that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not for questions like "how to do this" so please do some search, try some code and then, if you have an issue with your code, post a question here.

Comment: HI Utsav, I will be needing only code written between second *and -

Comment: And what if you have three `*` before the `-`? Please edit your question to clarify your need; some sample data and desired result could be useful

Comment: NO there will be only two * before - , the sample data I have given in the question. I need 0112305V7 out of BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR.  Means whatever is written after second * and before -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this with regexp:

```
select regexp_substr('BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR ','[[:digit:]]{3,}[[:alnum:]]{3,}') from dual;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace `str` with your column name):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, '*', 2) + 1, INSTR(str, '-') - INSTR(str, '*', 2) - 1)
```

**Note**: This will only work in the case your string consists of `__*__*XXXX-____`

Comment: I am getting MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 as result

Comment: Did you use exactly what I wrote? With the updated answer?

Comment: Yes I am doing the same           SELECT SUBSTR('BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR', INSTR('BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR', '*', 2) + 1,
INSTR('BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR', '-') - INSTR('BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR', '*', 2) - 1) str from dual

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your strings always have two `'*'` and a single `' - '` after the `'*'` occurrences, to get the value between the second `'*'` and the `' - '`, you can use :

```
select substr(str, instr(str, '*', 1, 2)+1, instr(str, ' - ') - instr(str, '*', 1, 2) -1) as theNeededString,
       instr(str, '*', 1, 2) as theSecondStar,
       instr(str, ' - ') - instr(str, '*', 1, 2)-1 as lengthOfTheNeededString
from ( select 'BY *MAN MOBILE*0112305V7 - JAIPUR ' str from dual)
```

Which gives a quite self_explanatory result:

```
THENEEDED THESECONDSTAR LENGTHOFTHENEEDEDSTRING
--------- ------------- -----------------------
0112305V7            15                       9
```